# Indexing only one MySQL column value

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb

I have a MySQL InnoDB table with a status column. The status can be 'done' or 'processing'. As the table grows, at most .1% of the status values will be 'processing,' whereas the other 99.9% of the values will be 'done.' This seems like a great candidate for an index due to the high selectivity for 'processing' (though not for 'done'). Is it possible to create an index for the status column that only indexes the value 'processing'? I do not want the index to waste an enormous amount of space indexing 'done.'

Comment: Just wondering if it would be easier to convert to a bit column named "processing" where the value would be either "1" or "0". Would use less space. (Unless you have more then 2 statuses)

Comment: Good suggestion. I actually do have more than 2 statuses, but I simplified it for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: "but I simplified it for the sake of simplicity" - that's okay then, as long as you didn't simplify it for some other reason :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any standard way to do this but we have solved a similar problem before by using two tables, `Processing` and `Done` in your case, the former with an index, the latter without.

Assuming that rows don't ever switch back from `done` to `processing`, here's the steps you can use:

1. When you create a record, insert it into the `Processing` table with the column set to `processing`.
2. When it's finished, set the column to `done`.
3. Periodically sweep the `Processing` table, moving `done` rows to the `Done` table.

That last one can be tricky. You can do the insert/delete in a transaction to ensure it transfers properly or you could use a unique ID to detect if it's already transferred and then just delete it from `Processing` (I have no experience with MySQL transaction support which is why I'm also giving that option).

That way, you're only indexing a few of the 99.9% of `done` rows, the ones that have yet to be transferred to the `Done` table. It will also work with multiple states of `processing` as you have alluded to in comments (entries are only transferred when they hit the `done` state, all other states stay in the `Processing` table).

It's akin to having historical data (stuff that will never change again) transferred to a separate table for efficiency. It can complicate some queries where you need access to both `done` and non-`done` rows since you have to join two tables so be aware there's a trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

Better solution: don't use strings to indicate statuses. Instead use constants in your code with descriptive names => integer values. Then that integer is stored in the database, and MySQL will work a LOT faster than with strings.

I don't know what language you use, but for example in PHP:

```
class Member
{
   const STATUS_ACTIVE = 1;
   const STATUS_BANNED = 2;
}

if ($member->getStatus() == Member::STATUS_ACTIVE)
{
}
```

instead of what you have now:

```
if ($member->getStatus() == 'active')
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The strings are in fact ENUMs, which means they are being mapped to integers. While your suggestion is a valid one, it does not get to the root of my question: Is it necessary to, and if so how do I, index only a specific value in a column?